Error: There were errors reading plugin package (please check also your plugin's metadata). Could not unzip file
I'm trying to upload a new version of my plugin in QGIS repository and I get this error, I checked the metadata and it's good. I don't know what is the problem.
The content of zip file is: i18n folder, About.ui, compile.bat, Dialog.ui, Helpfile.ui, icon.png, Makefile, metadata.txt, pb_tool.cfg, plugin_upload.py, my_plugin.py, pylintrc, my_plugin_dockwidget.py, my_plugin_dockwidget_base.ui, requirements.txt, resources.py, resources.qrc; my_plugin_help.chm, my_plugin_help.chw, and A text file to containing this :
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.3\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.3\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.3\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc


I found the answer to this problem. I stored the files in a folder before zipping it, and it worked.
